# Intellij How to ignore a file with errors?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I have a couple of separate applications which dont really depend on each other (and sometimes associated tests). Sometimes one of them has an error (cant find a package to import or so) and I really dont have time to fix it because I need to work on something else, I have no other choice but completely commenting out the offending file. Can I tell Intellij  To please just ignore a certain file when I want to execute another application?

Answer (score 1):

You should move the separate applications to separate modules. When you run an application, it will compile only the module containing this application and its dependencies, and will not compile the other modules.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, mostly the structure of these projects is given so I'm not as free to move around things as I might like.

Answer (score 1):

Under "Project Settings" -> "Module", exclude the package you don't want to run:

[image: Excluded Option]